# Definitive guide to network and dns configuration on Ubuntu 18.04 workstation?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

I'm finding it difficult to find reliable up-to-date information on how networking configuration is managed on Ubuntu 18.04 workstation.

I believe in `16.04` `dnsmasq` was the new kid on the block, and it took over duties from `resolved`

I recently found out about `netplan` though. [This link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-server-18-04/) refers to `netplan` for managing DNS, but it seems to only really apply to `ubuntu-server`, as the netplan configuration file on my workstation offloads everything to `NetworkManager`:

```
$ cat  /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

I guess I'm just confused as to what is responsible for what, there is a lot of confusing information about `ifupdown`, `resolved`, `dnsmasq`, `netplan`, `nm`, etc.

How can I get reliable, up-to-date information on whatever the state-of-the-art is for all things networking in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: See [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-a-Network-in-Ubuntu).

Comment: "offloads everything to NetworkManager" Then I suggest that is the place to make your settings: https://forum.manjaro.org/uploads/default/original/2X/d/d4c5b60c39bbdd4c58420445e2d1ef7e04821ac0.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short... you actually have multiple questions...

## NetworkManager vs Netplan

- In older versions of Ubuntu, **NetworkManager** was king.
- In newer versions of Ubuntu, **Netplan** and **systemd-resolved** tries to be king.

Unless you're running a server, I'd recommend staying with **NetworkManager**.

$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

- further netplan examples can be seen [here](https://netplan.io/examples).

## dnsmasq vs systemd-resolved

- In older versions of Ubuntu, **dnsmasq** was king.
- In newer versions of Ubuntu, **systemd-resolved** tries to be king.

If you must run them both, you'll want to modify the following, or DNS errors will occur.

Do a `ps auxc | grep -i dns` and `ps auxc | grep -i resolv` and look for `dnsmasq` and `systemd-resolved`, and if both are running, you need to disable the DNS part of `systemd-resolved` by editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and...

change:

```
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

to:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

## /etc/resolv.conf

- Do **NOT** manually edit this file.
- if this file contains 127.0.0.1, then dnsmasq is managing this file.
- if this file contains 127.0.0.53, then systemd-resolved is managing this file.
- if you wish to add specific DNS servers, use the GUI for "Wired Connection", or your wireless connection profile.